# Using Google Charts, with Date information

Tags: c#, google-visualization

I have the following data being returned from a c# method:

```
 <input id="hdMessageCountByVDate" type="hidden"    
  value="[{"Count":43,"Type":"3","Date":"2013-04-14"},
  {"Count":3,"Type":"2","Date":"2013-03-11"}]" name="hdMessageCountByVDate">
```

what i'm looking to do, is to create a graph, which shows the following:

total Count (43,2), with the associated type (3,2) on a given date (2013-04-14,2013-03-11)

currently there are only two entries, but these will increase of time, so the dates will vary.

How do i put this data into a chart that can be rendered correctly.

I have this so far:

```
         function drawMessageByVDate() {
            var hdValue = document.getElementById("<%=hdMessageCountByVDate.ClientID%>").value;
            var response = $.parseJSON(hdValue);
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

            data.addColumn('string', 'Type');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Count');
            data.addColumn('string', 'Date');

            for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                var row = new Array();
                row[0] = response[i].Type;
                row[1] = parseInt(response[i].Count);
                row[1] = response[i].Date;

                data.addRow(row);
            }
            var options = {
                title: 'My chart'


            };


            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById
            ('msgCountByVDate_Chart'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
```

Comment: Anyone? Can't seem to work this one out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Initial Thoughts:**

It looks like you have a bug where

```
row[1] = response[i].Date;
```

should be

```
row[2] = response[i].Date;
```

In addition, if you want Google to handle the dates properly, it appears that the api expects an actual javascript date object, not just a string representation of the date.  For modern browsers, this might be as simple as

```
data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
....
row[2] = new Date(response[i].Date);
```

However, to support older browsers (e.g. IE<9), you will probably need something more complex such as

```
data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
....
var d = response[i].Date;
row[2] = new Date(parseInt(d.substr(0,4)), parseInt(d.substr(5,2))-1, parseInt(d.substr(8,2)));
```

**Further Research**
It looks like Google actually expects a pivoted version of the data such as

```
Date       | Type 2 | Type 3
2013-04-14 |      0 |     43
2013-03-11 |      3 |      0
```

See https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#column_chart for examples

Comment: Thanks redo make, I shall give it a try later on.

Comment: erdomke - 'All series on a given axis must be of the same data type' is displayed.

Comment: i've tried calling the BarChart and ColChart, with the same effect

Comment: Yes, you can't mix dates and numbers together. That doesn't work. How do you expect the date to be plotted? I think you have a much more fundamental problem in how you are going about this, and should be clearer in your initial question what you expect the output to be, and also what the input is (so that we can test it).

Comment: jmac, forgive me, but have you read the above piece, clear on what data i have and what i want to do with it!

Comment: Anyone for anymore suggestions / example?

Comment: Thanks erdomke that helped a lot.